# Search users within specific kilometers in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am building script to search users within kilometers in laravel. Here's my code:

```
if ($request->has('city')) {

   $latitude = app('geocoder')->geocode($request->city)->get()->first()->getCoordinates()->getLatitude(); 
   $longitude = app('geocoder')->geocode($request->city)->get()->first()->getCoordinates()->getLongitude();

   $user->whereHas('user_data', function($query) use ($request, $latitude, $longitude) {
       return $query->whereRaw("( 6371 * acos ( cos ( radians(".$latitude.") ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(".$longitude.") ) + sin ( radians(".$latitude.") ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) <= ". $request->distance .")")->get();
           });
        }
```

but the problem is that I am getting an error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `user_datas` where `user_datas`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` and ( 6371 * acos ( cos ( radians(52.406374) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(16.9251681) ) + sin ( radians(52.406374) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) <= 10))
```

How to repair this and make code works?

Answer (score 0):

How about...

```
$users = App\Users::whereRaw("( 6371 * acos ( cos ( radians(".$latitude.") ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(".$longitude.") ) + sin ( radians(".$latitude.") ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) <= ". $request->distance .")")->get();
```